# Align figure vertically in minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, a0poster

I am trying to create a header of a A0 poster using `minipages`. Currently, my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

\renewcommand{\huge}{\fontsize{51.6}{64}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\veryHuge}{\fontsize{74.3}{93}\selectfont}

\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt
\columnseprule=3pt

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\linewidth}
   \veryHuge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Very long and overly complicated\\ scientific title}
   \\
   \huge \color{Black} \textbf{John Doe$^1$ \& John Smith$^2$}\\[0.5cm]
   \huge $^1$University 1\\[0.4cm]
   \huge $^2$University 2\\[0.4cm]
\end{minipage}%
~
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{logo.png}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

In the pdf, this results in the following.

[image: result]

What I would like is for the image of the logo to be vertically aligned so it sits in the centre of the `minipage`. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try removing the two `[b]` position specifiers from the `minipage` environments? Incidentally, since the combined width of the `minipage` environments is `\textwidth`, you should probably remove the `~` spacer. A separate matter: How and/or where is `\veryHuge` defined?

Comment: I tried to compile it and test some things, but there seem some definitions/packages to be missing (e.g. `\veryHuge`)?  If you'd update your code to make it work we could experiment with it more easily.

Comment: I have updated the preamble of the document. Removing the `[b]` position specifiers already gave me a very nice result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that last `\\[0.4cm]` in the first `minipage` and remove also the option `[b]` from `minipage`s, they are naturally vertically centered as you need.

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt
\columnseprule=3pt
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
   \veryHuge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Very long and overly complicated\\ scientific title} \\
   \huge \color{Black} \textbf{John Doe$^1$ \& John Smith$^2$}\\[0.5cm]
   \huge $^1$University 1\\[0.4cm]
   \huge $^2$University 2
\end{minipage}%
~
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]